# What is the subtle difference between ‘just about’ and ‘only just’?

Tags: meaning, differences, adverbs, nuance

I'm curious about the difference between sentences 1 and 2:

> 1. The company is just about ticking over.
> 2. The company is only just ticking over.

I guess the first describes a better situation than the second, doesn't it?
But different people seem to have different  opinions on this.

Comment: I’m curious about what it means for a company to tick over.

Comment: Whatever it means, sentence one implies that ticking over marks the end of something. Sentence 2 implies it marks the beginning.

Comment: I'd rather be only just ticking over than just about ticking over. The "just about" implies has not yet. Naturally, it's important to consider whether the company is say a startup, or a long going concern producing obsoleted products. **Ticking over:** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tick-over To not tick over is a *bad* thing, but that 'just about' might be interpreted as 'is about to start' ticking over, perhaps wildly.

Comment: 'just ticking over' is a metaphor, comparing the company to an engine.  You could also just 'just getting by' or 'just barely making it' or 'just barely making ends meet'.

Comment: The key could be how to interpret the opposite of "ticking over".

If a vehicle is ticking over, it is working but not in a powerful way.
What's a vehicle like if it is not ticking over? Theoretically, there are two polar possibilities: it cold be motionless, or it could be working in a powerful manner.

By metaphorical extension, if a company is just about (= almost) ticking over, it is not ticking over. Two polar possibilities arise: it could either be close to "motionless", i.e. almost inoperative, or be acquiring some business.

Answer (score 1):

As [Wayfaring Stranger](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6752/wayfaring-stranger) pointed out in the comments, *[ticking over](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tick-over)* means "continuing to work".

*Just about ticking over* means "almost ticking over" or "very close to ticking over". The phrase carries a connotation of anticipation; it implies that the company may be ticking over in the near future.

*Only just ticking over* actually has two possible meanings: "barely ticking over"<sup>[1](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/only+just)</sup> and "recently ticking over"<sup>[2](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/only+just)</sup>. The first meaning has a more pessimistic connotation: the company is ticking over, but it could be doing a lot better, and it could stop ticking over at any time. The second meaning is more neutral; it's just a statement about when something happened.

Which situation is "better" depends on which meaning of *only just* you pick, as well as your expectations for the future.